# Is there a word to represent the feeling on never being somewhere before?

Tags: single-word-requests

When I go to a new place there is a feeling of seeing everything for the first time, and the newness of it, but even just the second time I know where things are (vaguely) and its not much of a surprise. Is there a word for the feeling of newness and exploring of going somewhere new? I want to use this word to say things like "right now im experiencing a strong feeling of [insert word here]" like a contrapositive for wanderlust.

Comment: People feel lots of things when they visit a foreign (unfamiliar) place. If you can't even express what you feel, how can we guess at what it is in a single word? "Newness" is the best you can do? This is just a guessing game.

Comment: @medica Then we must build one! What shall we call this new word?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4732/2085).

Comment: @tchrist thanks for that, Im usually a poster on math.se so this was unfamiliar territory to me.

Comment: Since you say the next time it wasn't much of a surprise, I guess the first time what you felt was _surprise_.

Comment: **wonder**: a feeling of surprise, admiration, or pleasure that you get, for example when you have seen something very unusual or beautiful [Macmillan]

Comment: George Carlin already came up with a phrase for the opposite of _deja vu_... _vuja de_.

Comment: @ExUmbris vuja de is how i will now refer to this feeling. Thank you for this wonderful phrase. It shall serve its purpose well.

Comment: @JohnJPershing If so, [_jamais vu_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamais_vu) is then properly what you're looking for, used to describe any familiar situation that is not recognized

Answer (score 2):

Adventure, alien, foreign are the first words that comes to mind.

Uuncharted territory/waters would be the next.

Comment: Uncharted territory is a good noun, but im looking for and adjective or a noun that describes the feeling

Comment: @JohnJPershing Perhaps wide-eyed, overwhelmed, novel, thrilled (as above). You could say that you are bubbling with excitement.

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to the experience as ***eye-opening***

> [eye-opening:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/eye-opening)
>
> 1) causing a strong emotional reaction because of unexpectedness
>   *(hunting for a first apartment in a big city is an eye-opening experience for young people)*
>
> 2) causing wonder or astonishment

Additionally, consider the term: *the* *[thrill](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/thrill) of discovery.*

Comment: I like that, but im not looking for the feeling of finding something new, but the feeling of unknown things around every corner, regardless of how boring they might be. Just the feeling that i dont know it, not a strong emotion.

Comment: @JohnJPershing are you ***in awe*** of your surroundings?

Comment: I love the word "awesome." It's a shame it has been misused for so long now.

Answer (score 1):

Is *feeling of discovery* the term you're looking?

> **discovery**: the act of finding or learning something for the first time; the act of discovering something

Answer (score 0):

At first I was think *initiate*.  This is OK.  The better term is **oriented**.

> find one's position in relation to new and strange surroundings.

Answer (score 0):

I think that "[surprise](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Surprise)" may describe the sense of newness you are referring to when visiting  a place where everything is experienced for the first time and is  sort of unexpected to your eyes.

> Something, such as an unexpected encounter, event, or gift, that surprises.